# Making a portfolio website with Django and got Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm making a portfolio website with Django, it was going fine but in the last steps following a guide I got this error

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in personal_portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
projects/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

[image: Project Folder]

This is my project folder

Here is personal_portfolio - urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("projects/", include("projects.urls")),
]
```

And projects - urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="project_index"),
    path("int:pk>/", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
]
```

Also the section in settings.py

```
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects',
]
```

Here is the link of the repo of the guide I'm following https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/rp-portfolio

I downloaded the repo and tried to run the server and got the same error, how?
Also I searched here people with the same error even someone who was following the same guide but their solution didn't help mine and it was the same project

Comment: There is indeed no way that `/` can result to a page. To get the `project_index`, you here should visit `/projects/`.

Comment: But why it lead me to an error when I followed every step of the guide and I even downloaded the repo with the project that should be working?

Comment: well where in the project does it say that the `/` path will trigger a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request to the `http://localhost:8000/` endpoint will indeed not trigger a view, since the `project_index` view is located under the `http://localhost:8000/projects/` endpoint.

If you want to change this, you should alter the path to the `projects.url` with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projects.urls')),
]
```

There is also a typo in the `projects/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_index, name='project_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.project_detail, name='project_detail'),
]
```

Comment: I saw this same answer for someone who had the same mistake, I tried it but still got the same error. Not Found: /
[13/Jul/2020 20:46:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2042

Comment: @Carlos: did you restart the server?

Comment: I got this now NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'project_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['int:pk>/$']

Comment: @Carlos: ah but that is due to a typo in the `projects/urls.py`, it should be `<int:pk>`, not `int:pk>`.